# Как продолжить выполнение кода после того как if = true?

Tags: python, telebot, if

**Я хотел сделать проверку для числа которое вводит пользователь, с помощью if но когда я сделал 3 условия я обнаружил что когда выполняется 1 if а он выполнится всегда то остальные не выполняются без никакой ошибки просто не проверяются остальные if, можете подсказать почему или представить другое решение (как по другому сделать)P.s я еще с return пробовал тоже самое не получилось**

````
def check_callback_data(callback):
       sent = bot.send_message(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, text='Чтобы вырашивать яйца нужно отправить уток, введите кол-во уток:')
       bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, review) #сохраняет следующее сообщение в переменную
       
def review(message): #обработка этого сообщения
       
       if message.text.isdigit(): #проверка число или строка
          message_to = message.text
          if message_to == 1: # проверка равно ли введено число 1
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'не вводи 1')
            if message_to < 0: # проверка меньше 0 или больше
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id'число должно быть больше 0')
       else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Введите число')# исключение```
````

Comment: Проверьте, что внутри message_to: print(message_to)

Comment: Число которое ввел пользователь а так она пустая

Comment: Если она равна тому, что ввёл пользователь, тогда я не понимаю, почему не срабатывает If. Возможно пользовательские данные в формате str, а проверка идёт с Int. Сделайте printi(type(message_to)). Если там тип данных string, то "1" не равно 1 и условие не сработает.